# How to setup documents share URLs across multiple domains and cultures

Tags: culture, multiple-domains, kentico

i have a kentico site that has two culture specific domains (.co.nz and .com.au) and i want to setup multiple cultures so that the site has different versions of the some document in a sites tree.

I have all this working, however my problem is that i want the URL's to be the same on both domains and kentico doesn't allow you to have the same path for the two documents (it places a **-1** on the end of your path name if you enter them the same)

i am looking to have:

```
[domain name].com.au/products
[domain name].co.nz/products
```

point to the same document (in its respective culture version)

how have others achieved this?

Answer (score 2):

You simply can't have two different documents with the same URL in the same site, otherwise how would Kentico know which page to route to.

Either have a seperate url for the NZ version like
*audomain/products

nzdomain/products-nz*

Or consider separating them into two different sites in the same Kentico instance. Then you can share content across the sites by creating linked documents. This also allow you to have separate content on each site if required.